# ListBox only shows subset of data

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox

I'm trying to prove that using `DataSource` in a ListBox is much faster than using `Items.Add`. So I made a little WF app with two list boxes and a textbox that displays the times. `Items.Add` takes 15 seconds, `DataSource = list` takes one. Mission accomplished.

However... I noticed that the list boxes are showing only perhaps 1,000 lines of 100,000. `ListBox1.Items.Count` returns 100,000. When you scroll past about the 2/3 location and release, the scroller "snaps back" to about 1/2 way down the box, as if we're at the half-way point. Pulling it down again returns to the same spot again.

I assume there is a setting for the number of rows displayed, but I can't seem to find anything interesting. Anyone know what's happening here?

Comment: Do you really expect a user to scroll through 100,000 items? I think the way you are approaching this should be reconsidered...Also the ***max items is 32,000*** which is right on about your 2/3 spot...

Comment: In my test environment `ListBox` containing `65542` items can scroll without any problem.  (WIN7 SP1 .NET 4.0)

Comment: @Zaggler as I clearly explained, this is a test app to compare performance.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz that's fine, but I also answered `I assume there is a setting for the number of rows displayed, but I can't seem to find anything interesting.`, I was just making a statement, no pun intended :)

Comment: @Zaggler yes, it looks like 64k is set in stone. Which is fine, the actual target apps has a max of maybe 500. Oddly I did Google all over for this answer, but didn't find it because I used "max number of items". Replacing "items" with "rows" and presto. You'd think Google would get that one!

Comment: It is ***just Google***. Have a great day!

Comment: It's a little more than 64K, it's `65542` ;)

Comment: Lol @Reza Aghaei yes didn't think the precision really mattered.... Although 500+ items are a difference.

Comment: By the way, using `AddRange` seems to be faster than setting `DataSource`, if you are looking for a faster way, because setting `DataSource` uses `AddRange` internally.